# Multi str for Exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7

I have my own exception:

```
class NoSourceFileError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, logger, massage):
        Exception.__init__(self, massage)
        logger.logger.info(massage)
```

And it's calls with:

```
    ...
    else:
        raise NoSourceFileError('ERROR: can not find file %s for %s' % (add_file, add_name))
```

Problem here as you see - that I pass two variables (`add_file`, `add_name`) - but `__init__` can accept only one var (`message`).

How can I pass both of them?

I tried play with `*args` - but can't make it work.

`Logger` - my additional class for logging.

Comment: What do you really want with them?

Comment: Why you are passing `logger` object as argument to `__init__` it would be available within whole module once you had imported.

Comment: Have you tried running it? Evaluation of `'ERROR: can not find file %s for %s' % (add_file, add_name)` results in a single string, so only a single argument is passed to `NoSourceFileError.__init__`. The problem I see is that you defined `NoSourceFileError.__init__` with three parameters (two, excluding `self`), so `raise` statement won't work.

Comment: @Scironic, see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html

Comment: @Werkritter, in which case a secondary issue is the lack of a capital `L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the `string`, which is fine. It is that you are passing `logger` into the `exception`.

Remove the `logger` parameter (and usage) and it will work:

```
>>> class NoSourceFileError(Exception):
...     def __init__(self, message):
...         Exception.__init__(self, message)
...

>>> raise NoSourceFileError('ERROR: can not find file %s for %s' % ('x', 'y'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.NoSourceFileError: ERROR: can not find file x for y
>>>
```

I'm not sure what `logger` is meant to be. But if you want to use it, you need to pass it as an `argument` to the `exception` when raising it.

On string formatting, it on it's own will always count as a single argument assuming it is done right. So can't count for more than 1.

As @werkritter has said, if you do want to use logger without having to pass it in as a parameter - define it globally. I will assume that it is meant to log errors, in which case it would make sense to have it defined globally anyway.

Comment: You removed `logger.logger.info(massage)` from `NoSourceFileError.__init__`. If you added it back, and mentioned that it should be defined globally, on at a higher scope, then the answer would be complete.

Comment: @werkritter - I've excluded it specifically because I don't know what it is. Although I will add your comment to the answer.

Comment: OMG, I need more coffee... Sure - error was caused because of `logger` object wasn't passed :-) `raise NoSourceFileError(logger, 'ERROR: can not find file %s for %s' % (add_file, add_name))` - works fine. Thanks.